# How to use fl_image function in Moviepy within Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, movieclip, moviepy

I want to save a video into another file using different name. Thus, I have following codes to handle this question:

```
def process_image_1(image):
  img=mpimg.imread(image)
  return img;
```

Also, I have

```
output='output.mp4'
clip1 = VideoFileClip("Right.mp4")
clip = clip1.fl_image(process_image_1)
%time clip.write_videofile(output, audio=False)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object
```

I am not sure what's wrong with it, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 8):

The `fl_image` function accepts an image function as parameter, so the parameter passed to the image function `process_image_1` should be an image, but not the path to an image.

Remove the line `img=mpimg.imread(image)` and read the image file outside of the image function, e.g.

```
result = process_image(mpimg.imread(image))
```

and it shall work.